# Lifetimes for type params, "the parameter type may not live long enough"

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have code like this (this is how `#[async_trait]` is expanded):

```
trait BoolTrait {
    fn check<'s: 'f, 'v: 'f, 'f>(&'s self, value: &'v i32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = bool> + 'f>>;
}
```

Actually it says that `Future ('f)` can contain refs to `self ('s)` and `v ('v)`, so lifetime of `'s` and `'v`  must be longer than `Future 'f` lifetime.

Next, I want to make any closure with async body implement this trait:

```
impl<F, Fut> BoolTrait for F
    where
        F: Fn(&i32) -> Fut,
        Fut: Future<Output = bool> {
    fn check<'s: 'f, 'v: 'f, 'f>(&'s self, value: &'v i32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=bool> + 'f>> {
        Box::pin(self(value))
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
error[E0309]: the parameter type `Fut` may not live long enough
   |
16 | impl<F, Fut> BoolTrait for F
   |         --- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `Fut: 'f`
...
21 |         Box::pin(self(value))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `Fut` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

Okay, let's try `'static` lifetime, just to make it compile (actually I think that my problem is here, but I don't know what correct lifetime should I use):

```
Fut: Future<Output = bool> + 'static
```

Let's check how it works:

```
async fn test<BT: BoolTrait>(bt: BT) {
    let v = 42;
    bt.check(&v).await;
}

fn main() {
    block_on(test(|v: &i32| async { *v == 42 }));
}
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:13:39
   |
13 |         block_on(test(|v: &i32| async { *v == 42 }));
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 13:23...
  --> src/lib.rs:13:23
   |
13 |         block_on(test(|v: &i32| async { *v == 42 }));
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:13:39
   |
13 |         block_on(test(|v: &i32| async { *v == 42 }));
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `&&i32`
              found `&&i32`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `impl futures::Future` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:13:18
   |
13 |         block_on(test(|v: &i32| async { *v == 42 }));
   |                  ^^^^
```

And this is where I am. Actually, I can fix it, by replacing `value: &i32` param with `value: i32`, but it's not I want, I want to use exactly reference.

If I correctly understand the error, the compiler says that Future lives shorter than ref to `i32`, because it contains ref to it, but in the trait impl I set `'static`.

It seems to me, that I need to specify somehow that the lifetime of `Fut` must be shorter than the lifetime `&i32`, in `impl`.